# seleccionar una opcion con multiples select

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

Lo que quiero es que al existir varios select cada uno cambie un id no se si me explico, quiero que al seleccionar presente aparezca un input y si esta permiso desaparezca el input pero serán varios select

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myDIV {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDIV">
  <h3>A h3 element in div.</h3>
  <p>P element in div.</p>
  <span>A span element in div.</span>
  <h2>A h2 element in div.</h2>
  <div>A div element in div.</div>
  <p>Another p element in div.</p>
</div>
<div id="myDIV">
  <h3>A h3 element in div.</h3>
  <p>P element in div.</p>
  <span>A span element in div.</span>
  <h2>A h2 element in div.</h2>
  <div>A div element in div.</div>
  <p>Another p element in div.</p>
</div>

<p>Click the button to add a background color to all elements inside the div element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    var y = x.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        y[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
</script>

<select name="condicion" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
                                    <option value="1">PRESENTE</option>
                                    <option value="2">PERMISO</option>
                                </select>

<select name="condicion" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
                                    <option value="1">PRESENTE</option>
                                    <option value="2">PERMISO</option>
                                </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, puedes explicar mayores detalles por favor? Estoy leyendo repetidas veces y sigo sin entender lo que deseas lograr. Por cierto, date una vuelta por el sitio: http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para que te familiarices. Saludos :D

Answer (score 0):

Debes colocar un id o un name distinto a los selects que ya tienes creados para poder distinguirlos en tu código. Después, creas el input que quieres mostrar, pero dentro de sus atributos CSS le estableces "visibility: hidden" o "display: none". Luego, dentro de tu código Javascript preguntas con un if-else por el valor del parámetro que enviaste a la función. Si cumple la condición que deseas, cambias el valor de visibilidad del input o no.
Espero que te ayude.